# how to specify outputfilecommitter / algorithm for hive on emr 6.4

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr

I'm trying to migrate from EMR 5.18 to EMR 6.4 and it appears that hive is now using mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version value of 1 even though I have it configured to 2 as follows:

```
{
  "Classification": "core-site",
  "Properties": {
    ...
    "mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version": "2",
    ...
  }
}
```

This worked in 5.18. In 5.18 I see messages like the following during the rename phase:

```
2021-10-28 07:33:13,691 [INFO] [TezChild] |s3n2.S3NativeFileSystem2|: rename s3://**********/.hive-staging_hive_2021-10-28_07-30-50_813_8017322768660599110-1/_task_tmp.-ext-10000/_tmp.000001_0 s3://***********/.hive-staging_hive_2021-10-28_07-30-50_813_8017322768660599110-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000001_0
2021-10-28 07:33:14,481 [INFO] [TezChild] |exec.FileSinkOperator|: RECORDS_OUT_1_default.**************:3860
```

In 6.4 (with the same core-site configI see the following:

```
2021-10-28 15:09:31,116 [INFO] [TezChild] |s3n.S3NativeFileSystem|: rename s3://*****/.hive-staging_hive_2021-10-28_14-55-19_880_6458647626005146122-1/_task_tmp.-ext-10000/_tmp.000001_0 s3://*****/.hive-staging_hive_2021-10-28_14-55-19_880_6458647626005146122-1/_tmp.-ext-10000/000001_0.avro using algorithm version 1
2021-10-28 15:09:31,617 [INFO] [TezChild] |exec.FileSinkOperator|: RECORDS_OUT_1_default.****:384, RECORDS_OUT_OPERATOR_FS_20:384, RECORDS_OUT_INTERMEDIATE_Reducer_4:0,
```

Is there a way to specify version 2 for hive?

Or is there a way to use the EMRFS S3-optimized committer with hive? I know it is used by default by spark, but I can't find a way to enable it for hive (nor is it clear if I can or should).

Thanks in advance.